# Array Formula for TEXTJOIN Based on Date & Catergory & Planned or Actual

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column for every day of the year, a column for different tasks, and a category for each task. Some of the categories are one off, others duplicate between tasks. Each task has nearly 400 items (rows) that could be assigned, and has a planned quantity and an actual quantity per item.

I can get the TEXTJOIN array to work in a Total to Date dataset. The Total to Date dataset merges all of the categories into one row for planned and another row for actual. However, I need results for up to ten days of data: Tomorrow, Today, Yesterday, Today-2, etc. for reporting purposes. Having the Total to Date dataset alone is nearly 14,000 formulas. I cannot do that for ten days and expect the sheet to work at a reasonable pace. 
I need an array formula that is capable of looking up individual rows based on the date & category & planned or actual (creating a unique value to lookup). Based on the row(s) with the unique value(s), any item that has a quantity needs to be listed in the TEXTJOIN.

This is the code that works for the Total to Date dataset:

`{=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(INDIRECT(CELL("address",INDEX($1:$1048576,MATCH($D146,$E:$E,0),COLUMN(INDEX(TRACKING_Sheets,1,1))))&":"&CELL("address",INDEX($1:$1048576,MATCH($D146,$E:$E,0),COLUMN(INDEX(TRACKING_Sheets,1,1))+COLUMNS(TRACKING_Sheets)-1)))<>"",TRACKING_Sheets,""))}`

Here is a picture that is probably worth a thousand words for this problem.

[Proposed Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jJzF.png)

[All Tasks in One Day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQrSW.png)

Hopefully I explained this well enough. Thank you for your time.

I'm using Excel 365 ProPlus 64bit

Comment: You have merged cells I would get rid of immediately if I was you. That's going to give you trouble because they hold cells that (most likely) won't have any value to compare against. Would make building a formula a lot easier.

Comment: BTW you can get rid of all the ADDRESS/INDIRECTS: `=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,if(INDEX($1:$1048576,MATCH($D146,$E:$E,0),COLUMN(INDEX(TRACKING_Sheets,1,1))):INDEX($1:$1048576,MATCH($D146,$E:$E,0),COLUMN(INDEX(TRACKING_Sheets,1,1))+COLUMNS(TRACKING_Sheets)-1)<>"",TRACKING_Sheets,""))`

Comment: And do your columns change that much that you need it to be so dynamic in references?  Couldn't you make it simpler: `=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,if(INDEX($G:$P,MATCH($D146,$E:$E,0),0)<>"",$G$1:$P$1,""))`

Comment: @ScottCraner: Both of your formulas work to get the items from the first row with the unique value, but not the second. The result for both of them are 1, 5, 8. The expected result is 1, 2, 5, 8.

Comment: @JvdV: The merged cells are only used for creating the unique value. A1&C1&E1 then A2&C1&E2 that pattern lets me drag and drop the formula all the way down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a result based on the date, category, and planned, try...

```
    =TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(ROW($G$2:$P$6))^0,IF($D$2:$D$6=R2&S2&T2,IF($G$2:$P$6<>"",1,0),0))>0,$G$1:$P$1,""))

...where R2 contains the date, S2 contains the category, and T2 contains Planned.
```

For a result based on the date, category, and planned or actual combined, try...

```
    =TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(ROW($G$2:$P$6))^0,IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($D$2:$D$6,R2&S2&T2:T3,0)),IF($G$2:$P$6<>"",1,0),0))>0,$G$1:$P$1,""))

...where R2 contains the date, S2 contains the category, T2 contains Planned, and T3 contains Actual.
```

Note that both formulas need to be confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER.  Adjust the range accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. I've already began using it in my production sheet.

Comment: Is there a way to get the same results using another means? My boss only has Professional Plus 2013 and that version doesn't support TEXTJOIN. Should I create another thread for this issue or can we just tweak the formula here?

Comment: Have a look at the custom function [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1108468-array-formula-textjoin-periodically-not-updating-returning-correct-values-post5334368.html#post5334368).